# Should I Load All Data Once or One Row At A Time -- MySQL -- C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am creating an application where I have n number of rows (in reality it will be 1 million+ rows) and need to know what do you think; is better  to implement?

The goal is I need to iterate through each row and for each of those rows do some cool things...however there are two ways to do this.

First Way:

```
SELECT * FROM table and load them all into a list...
```

Second Way:

```
SELECT...LIMIT 1 and load 1 row, do the work on that row,then redo a SELECT...LIMIT 1 each time.
```

Which way is better when taking into consideration performance is important, memory is no problem, and constant lookups are not very expensive.

Comment: There's a middle ground. Chunk it into reasonably sized groups - perhaps a few thousand at a time.

Comment: _SELECT * FROM ALargeTable_ is a very bad idea because you need to wait a lot before starting your processing (and assuming that you really don't have memory problems) _SELECT...LIMIT 1..._ is a bad idea because you need to go back and forth between your code and the database a million of times. So, paging  IE LIMIT 1000.

Comment: You should not cut up the query yourself, just do a full select. The dataaccess layer will stream the results. (cut the result in parts)

Answer (score 1):

Just load batch of 1000 records at a time, process them and load the next 1000. This will reduce the amount of connections being setup/teared down and the amount of queries sent to the database server.